# Selecting the top 5 rows from a joined table, into the result of a larger query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Apologies for the rubbish title, but I can't think how to describe what I'm trying to do

Basically I'm trying to write a query that does the equivalent of the following

```
Firstname  Surname  Phone Number 1   Phone Number 2  ...  Phone Number 5
Bloggs     Joe      012334           09876           ...  05678
```

From the tables

```
(Person)
id  firstname  surname
1   Joe        Bloggs

(PhoneNumber)
id  personid  number
1   1         01234
2   1         09876
...
5   1         05678
```

But I can't work out how to do this without repeated (and messy) sub-queries

eg

```
SELECT
    Person.firstname,
    Person.surname,
    (SELECT top 1 PhoneNumber.number FROM PhoneNumber WHERE personid = Person.id) as [PhoneNumber1],
    (SELECT top 1 PhoneNumber.number FROM PhoneNumber WHERE personid = Person.id AND
        id NOT IN (SELECT top 1 PhoneNumber.number from PhoneNumber WHERE personid = Person.id)
    ) as [PhoneNumber2],
....
```

etc. This is clearly the wrong way to do it (or if not, it's grotesque, horrible code that I'll pretend I've never seen or been involved with)

Any suggestions?

(Also, I promise this isn't homework, nor something I tend to do... I'm just trying to simplify an existing report)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: If this is T-SQL, then you could use the [PIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) feature. But I can't promise that the resulting query would be any less grotesque. ;-)

Comment: SQL Server, if it makes any difference

Comment: Which version of MSSQL?

Comment: The report could in theory be used on various versions of SQL Express or SQL Server, as it's going out to several customers - a generic solution would be ideal, but if there's a solution which is limited to certain versions, I can live with that and advise accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a pivot query to do this. The query below is adapted for SQL Server 2012+ (as it uses the concat operator), if you need to use an older version just change to the line 
I left commented.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Person P
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
       Personid, 
       Number, 
       --RN = 'Phone Number ' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PERSONID ORDER BY ID) AS CHAR(1))
       RN = CONCAT('Phone Number ', ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PERSONID ORDER BY ID)) 
    FROM PhoneNumber
) PH ON P.ID = PH.PERSONID
PIVOT (
    MAX(Number) FOR RN IN ( 
       [Phone Number 1], 
       [Phone Number 2], 
       [Phone Number 3], 
       [Phone Number 4], 
       [Phone Number 5] 
    )
) AS Pivoted
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/db039/1) (with some more fake data)

Comment: This makes sense to me, although I can't get it working with my data (the phone number thing was an abstraction), but I'll have a play and see what I can come up with

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution with MSSQL 2012 only is using [`OFFSET`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618(v=sql.110).aspx).

```
SELECT
    Person.firstname,
    Person.surname,
    (SELECT number FROM PhoneNumber WHERE PhoneNumber.personid = Person.id 
     ORDER BY PhoneNumber.id OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY) AS number1,
    (SELECT number FROM PhoneNumber WHERE PhoneNumber.personid = Person.id 
     ORDER BY PhoneNumber.id OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY) AS number2,
    ...
FROM
    Person
```

See this [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/db039/8).

Comment: A little tidier, at least, thanks, although still a little too much repetition for my taste

Comment: Totally agree...  jpw solution seems nice.